# plugin for contact form magento2

Tags: magento2, plugin, contact-form

[image]im trying to make plugin for contact form to send email with the fields:

- first name
- last name
- phone
- comment
- email

last name email phone comment

Here my code

```
    <?php

namespace Convert\CustomContact\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper ;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface ;



class Post
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';
    protected $_escaper;
    protected $_contactConfig;
    protected  $_transportBuilder;
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $messageManager;

    // It's just a regular constructor with classes we want to use in our code
    public function __construct(
            DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
            Context $context,
            Escaper $escaper,
            TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
            StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
            ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder =$transportBuilder;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;


}
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject, $result)
    {

        if ($this->dataPersistor->get('contact_us')) {
            $post = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue();

            try{

            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            $sender = [
            'firstname' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['firstname']),
            'lastname' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['lastname'])           
            ];



            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template') 
            ->setTemplateOptions(
            [
            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
            ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($sender)
            ->setFrom($post['email'])
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->setReplyTo($replyToName)
            ->getTransport();
             $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );

             } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
            __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'.$e->getMessage())
            );


             }
           // return $this->context->getResultRedirectFactory()->create()->setPath('/');
        }
        return $result;
    }


}
```

The problem is that when i clicked on submit button of contact page, it didn't get the value of the first name and last name. Instead that, it still took the value of name field and print the alert name is missing.
Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: By default, there is no `First Name` or `Last Name` in contact form, there is only `Name`, which can be accessed by executing `$subject->getRequest()->getParam('name')`. Are you using custom contact form?

Comment: yes, i'm using custom form and what i want is to get the value of two custom fields first name and last name

Comment: Could you provide the data that are submitted by the custom form when you submit it? The easiest way if you use Chrome is by pressing F12 -> click on `Network` tab -> check the `Preserve log` -> fill in and submit the form -> click on the row that is capturing the form submission -> click on `Headers` tab. The submitted data are captured in `Request Headers` accordion.

Comment: you mean form data ?

Comment: firstname: Nguyễn
lastname: thủy
email: thuthuy210.tt@gmail.com
telephone: 
comment: ewgftwg
hideit: is that right?

Comment: what do you get if you use `$subject->getRequest()->getParam('firstname')` and `$subject->getRequest()->getParam('lastname')` instead of `$subject->getRequest()->getPostValue()`?

Comment: i just get the value of the first name and last name, but if i use getPostValue, i get all the value of all fields

Comment: I mean, do you get the value if you use `$subject->getRequest()->getParam('firstname')`?

Comment: Yes, i got the value

Comment: So you get the value using `getParam()` but you don't get the value using `getPostValue()`, which probably your form sends a GET method instead of POST method. `getParam()` gets all request data (including GET, POST, PUT) while `getPostValue()` only gets request data which is sent using POST method.

Comment: so that mean i have to use getParam() instead of using getPostValue()?

Comment: not always, it depends on how your contact form is submitted, whether using POST method or GET method.

Comment: Thanks, i have question is that when i click on submit button, it gets all the value and generates email template in admin, but the alert of name field still appearances. How can i fix it?

Comment: Could you please capture or record your screen while the issue happens and post it here? Actually I don't get what you explain.

Comment: i updated above, please check for me. Thanks

Comment: See here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ddf42caaf25311f10b23b95a92746f99943e045e/app/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php#L75

and here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ddf42caaf25311f10b23b95a92746f99943e045e/app/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php#L109

Comment: You don't pass the `name` parameter, while the controller checks for `name` parameter and throws an exception if the `name` parameter is missing or empty. That's why you still get the error message even when the email is sent successfully. You have to use around plugin and override the `execute` method to bypass the validation.